# Question regarding XST bitstream generation

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I have a very simple VHDL module, consisting of a few lines of code. The thing is, when I generate the bitstream, I end
up with a huge bitstream. The reason for this is, I guess, that XST adds lots of extra information so that the bitstream
can run standalone on a FPGA.

However, for my purpose it would be interesting to see the size of the bitstream of the module alone without any extra bits and pieces, just the vaniall module alone. Is there an option in Xilinx ISE 12.1 that allows me to do that?

Many thanks,
Richi

Answer (score 4):

The bitstream contains information for every configurable resource of the device you are targeting regardless of your actual design utilisation. When you program the FPGA the bitfile is clocked into the device, configuring the parts you are not using as well as the ones you are. The size of the bitfile is therefore dictated entirely by the target device.

If you want to see a breakdown of the resources your module is using, take a look at section "Section 14 - Utilization by Hierarchy" in the .mrp file generated by map.

Comment: Newer versions of PlanAhead (12.x) have very nice hierarchical views for seeing device utilization for implemented modules as well.

Answer (score 1):

As Chiggs said, the bitstream is always the same size for each device you're targeting. (You can see this by opening fpga_editor, saving an empty NCD file and converting into a bitstream... still the same size!) Or, in other words, every configuration memory cell *must* be set (with 0 or 1) on configuration.

But, in fact, you could do what you're asking. It's called dynamic reconfiguration, and for this the tools will generate bitstream pieces that together make an entire bitstream. First you configure the device with a regular bitstream and then you're able to dynamically reconfigure bitstream pieces on top of it *while the rest of the FPGA is running normally*! (Neat, no?)

Anyway, that's what you asked for, but I'm not sure that's what you wanted... what were you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Saar, yes exactly this is what I am trying to achieve. However, the procedure with Planahead to generate the partial bitstreams just takes a bit to long for my liking. I have quite a few different HW extensions that I wanna swap in, and it wanna be nice to have a rough estimation how big the bitstream is gonna be without going the Planahead route. So is there another way that I could get a quick estimation about the size of the bitstream? Somehwhere I read compression would give me a good indication. What do you think about this approach?

Comment: Seems to be nowhere close ... Partial bitstream is 50kB while the compressed bitstream of the exactly same module as standalone design is 250kB. So that is definitely not a good approximation, maybe I could use the scaling factor of 1/5 as a very rough estimation...

Comment: @Richi, I think that everyone would agree that partial/dynamic reconfiguration isn't easy -- you'll have to go through the hurdles because the process is complicated and buggy.

Comment: @Richi Compression results would depend on the algorithm it is using, so I wouldn't say that's reliable or consistent. I'd still go with the partial bitstream route.

Comment: @Richi, you still didn't quite answer my question: what are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: Alright, thanks Saar I thought that I have to go the painful route. What I wanna actually do: I have a reconfigurable design, and different ways of of to implement the module that is swapped in and out. As I wanna keep the partial bitstream as small as possible, it would have been nice to get a rough and quick estimation about its size so that I can immediatelly see if it fits my constrains or not. Would save me a considerable amout of time before doing the reconfigurable logic bit.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for jumping into the discussion but I do not think 250KB is a huge bitstream in any way! I use a very small FPGA of 3500 Logic slices and it gives me a bitstream of 3MB. One important thing to consider here. If you are trying to initialize any of your RAMs then the bitstream is going to carry extra bits which are initialization bits of the BRAM Blocks in the FPGA. that can just add additional memory to the bitstream. But on an average, it is the whole FPGA matrix that is getting written with the bits stored in the Offchip/OnChip Flash where the bitfile is stored, So it should not change from run to run.